# How to get back HTML5 page when I press back key at webapp?

Tags: android, html, button, back

there
I have a problem with android back key at webapp.
My status is that there is one html5 page.
There is a button at html5 page to call android intend method, so the page is moved to android activity. So far, so good.
The problem is that after pressing back button, android home launcher is shown up.
I wanna go back to html5 again when I press back button.
Can you give me some hint?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onBackPressed in the Android activity. I think the HTML5 page should still be present when you start this new activity which will come on top of the HTML5 page, so when you finish this activity, you should automatically go back to the HTML5 page.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
}
```